# How do I resolve the error "Binding already being used by a product other than IIS"

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have an SSL cert with its own unique IP address on a 2008 R2 server.  I have created a basic website using IIS Manager, with a file called “Hello.html” in the root.  When trying to add an https binding I receive the following error after choosing my certificate:

> This binding is already being used by
>   a product other than IIS. If you
>   continue you might overwrite the
>   existing certificate for this IP
>   Address:Port combnation. Do you want
>   to use this binding anyway?"

I click Yes to this prompt and the binding is created.  When I try to retrieve my file using the server’s own browser, the request times out.  I have another server which has a shared configuration with this one, and it works fine.  Does anyone have any suggestions how to find out which application may be using this binding other than IIS, and how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the new binding (SSL) using port 443? Make sure you do not use the same as another site. In other words, currently SSL can only support one site per IP/Port combination, so make sure you are adding it using port 443, and that no other site is running in the same IP, otherwise you will overwrite the certificate for the other site causing the browsers to report a certificate mismatch ugly warning.

Comment: Thanks, I've talked to my counterpart in IT, and he confirms that the site has its own IP.